# google colab: Missing the whole organization in the "Open Notebook" --> Github

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

When I try to open the private repository (created within a github organization) in google colab, the whole organization is missing from the file menu. I can access all the files on Github. Is there any setting that prevents it from showing up in the colab's open-file menus?

Answer (score 5):

Go to the GitHub settings of the organization. In the "Third-party applications" section, click "Remove Restrictions". After that I was able to see the all the repos, when opening from Google Colab.

Then I reverted the change by re-enabling the restrictions on the same page of GitHub settings.

Then I tried to open a private file from google colab. This time, I got a new pop-up window asking for GitHub access to the organization. After allowing, I can see all the repos from the organization.