# Google Colab cannot access github private "organization" Repos with Third Party Restrictions enabled

Tags: google-colaboratory, github-organizations

Goal: enable access to Github organization private repos from Google Colab and maintain Github Organization Restrictions as Third-party application access policy.

- Unable to see private "organization" repos in Google Colab from Github tab in open dialog box.
- Removed third party access restrictions in Github organization settings per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59827459/google-colab-missing-the-whole-organization-in-the-open-notebook-github).  Was able to see private repos for the organization.
- Saved a test .pynb file to private repo.  Was able to see and open. On opening, a gitlab permissions dialog flashed on the screen momentarily (was only able to read it by capturing with a camera [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwG3b.jpg)), and then the file opened in Gitlab.  Other than the spurious dialog, access is enabled, but third party access restrictions are not in place.
- After re-enabling restrictions per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59827459/google-colab-missing-the-whole-organization-in-the-open-notebook-github) I was only able to see public "organization" repos.  No permissions dialog was presented as described.

Answer (score 1):

When connecting from Google Colab to GitHub you can grant Colab access to your own private repos quite easily.
But when it comes to an organizations' repos it needs some extra steps.

1. Request access using the Colab [main page](https://colab.research.google.com/github/) and follow the instructions in the [colab-github-demo](https://colab.research.google.com/github/googlecolab/colabtools/blob/main/notebooks/colab-github-demo.ipynb#scrollTo=Rmai0dD30XzL).
2. Now an owner of your organization has to grant access in the "Third-party-settings".
3. Note that if you are also owner of the organization you get the "grant" option also on your private profile. Once granted and revoked there you will have to go to your organization settings to re-grant the access.